# Plotting Sequence of Records in F# Charting

Tags: f#, f#-charting

I am just starting out with F# and having some trouble understanding how to use a Sequence of Records with F# Charting.

I have a function (ReturnTemp) that returns a sequence of records of type TempData. TempData is defined by a record type as follows

```
type TempData = {Date: System.DateTime; Year: int64 ; Location: string; Temperature: decimal}
```

I am not clear on how to use this sequence with Chart.Line to plot Date on x axis and Temperature on Y axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that displays a line chart using a list of TempData records:

```
#r """..\packages\FSharp.Charting.0.90.7\lib\net40\FSharp.Charting.dll"""
#load """..\packages\FSharp.Charting.0.90.7\FSharp.Charting.fsx"""

open FSharp.Charting
open System

type TempData = {
    Date: System.DateTime
    Year: int64
    Location: string
    Temperature: decimal
}

let data =
    [
        {Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays -4.; Year = 2014L; Location = "City X"; Temperature = 13M}
        {Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays -3.; Year = 2014L; Location = "City X"; Temperature = 16M}
        {Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays -2.; Year = 2014L; Location = "City X"; Temperature = 12M}
        {Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays -1.; Year = 2014L; Location = "City X"; Temperature = 14M}
        {Date = DateTime.Today; Year = 2014L; Location = "City X"; Temperature = 18M}
    ]

data
|> List.map (fun x -> x.Date, x.Temperature)
|> Chart.Line
```

You can also use [FsPlot](http://tahahachana.github.io/FsPlot/) to generate a similar chart using Highcharts or Google Charts.

Comment: So just to be clear the only way to use it in the plotting function is to return a new list of tuples, i.e. you don't directly access the records in the list.

Comment: You can extend the Chart type with another Line static member that takes a sequence of TempData records if you want.